# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows でDVDドライブ上に移動できない

Tags: wsl

Bash on Ubuntu on Windows で、ノートPC内蔵DVDドライブの中身に移動したいのですが、ネットで調べると`cd /mnt/d`で移動できるとあったので試してみましたが、移動きません。

`cd /mnt/c`でCドライブには移動できます。
確かに、`cd /mnt`にはdドライブはありませんので当然の結果だと思います。

マウントしたDVD内をBash on Ubuntu on Windowsで確認する方法はありますでしょうか
因みにエクスプローラーで見ると、DVD RW ドライブ(D):となっております。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Windows のバージョン情報や、どこからインストールした WSL かが分かれば、追記頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: windows7からの自動アップデートで10に移行しました。ビルド17134.523です。下記ご回答いただいた`sudo mkdir /mnt/d`でアクセスできました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 [Build 16176](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-16176) 以降では、手動で CD/DVD ドライブをマウントすることで使えます。

たとえば `/mnt/d` に D ドライブをマウントしたい場合、以下のようにできます。

```sh
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d
$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```

アンマウントもできます。

```
$ sudo umount /mnt/d
```

より詳しくは、2017年4月のブログ記事 ["File System Improvements to the Windows Subsystem for Linux"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/) が参考になります。